# What is the need for Attribute encryption when Assertion encryption is enabled

Tags: security, encryption, saml-2.0

Attributes are part of Assertion, given this what is the value add to security doing double encryption once attributes and again assertion.

Will assertion encryption using strong encryption algorithm not suffice? If this is true why does SAML spec has both?

Comment: Can you give the context please?

Comment: If assertion encryption is enabled then do we need attribute encryption. Attributes are part of assertion and are automatically encrypted when assertion is encrypted.